# Iterating through server list in JSON format

Tags: json, powershell-4.0

I'm attempting to make a JSON file for a list of servers with specific parameters for each.  I then want to import the JSON into PowerShell as an object and be able to navigate the data accordingly.  Here is my first attempt:

```json
[
  {
  "Name": "server01",
  "Drives": [
        {"id": "C:", "threshold": 100},
        {"id": "F:", "threshold": 100}
    ],
    "Services": ["service1","service2","service3"] 
  },
  {
    "Name": "server02",
    "Drives": [
      {"id": "C:", "threshold": 100},
      {"id": "F:", "threshold": 100},
      {"id": "G:", "threshold": 100}
    ],
    "Services": ["service1","service2"] 
  }
]
```

PowerShell Script:

```
$svr = (Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\scripts\servers.json | ConvertFrom-Json)
$svr
```

Output

```
Name     Drives                                                                      Services
----     ------                                                                      --------
server01 {@{id=C:; threshold=100}, @{id=F:; threshold=100}}                          {service1, service2, service3}
server02 {@{id=C:; threshold=100}, @{id=F:; threshold=100}, @{id=G:; threshold=100}} {service1, service2}
```

This seems to work so far, however I need to be able to iterate through each one with something like a `foreach()` loop.  What is the best way to do this? Improvements to my JSON file?

Comment: Iterate through each one ... *what*? Server? Drive? Service? JSON file? Chocolate-frosted Sugar Bomb? What have you tried so far to iterate over the data? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: So, I have imported the JSON file and I need to be able to iterate through each "server" and its subsets, similar to a foreach loop in an array and I'm not sure how to do it.  I have tried a foreach, but it doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: Then please show what *exactly* you have tried, describe the result of your attempt, and explain what result you actually expected from your code. Do not post this information as a comment. Edit your question instead.